# LGA1151 motherboards with parallel port

Tags: port

USB-3, Thunder Bolt is today's standard, but I'm seeing a lot of boards still coming with a Parallel port on new motherboards with the LGA1151 socket.

Is the parallel port still in use for today's technology?

I am not talking about the serial port, but the 25-pin parallel port.

Some Examples
**Asus H110M-D** and the **Gigabyte GA-H110M-S2PH**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you're Asus, Gigabyte, etc. and you're designing a motherboard, the cost of adding a parallel port is practically non-existent if you're already putting a serial port on it.  Serial ports are still useful -- much more so than parallel ports.  But the thing is, the SAME chip controls both, so the question becomes "why not?" Both of the motherboards you linked to also have a serial port on them.

Secondly, a USB<->Parallel adapter takes the simplest of interfaces and makes it way more complicated than it should be.  Any time I encounter one of these adapters, I wind up spending more time getting the stupid adapter to work than I do getting the device that plugs into it to work.  Sometimes there's just no substitute for having an actual, physical parallel port.

There are several other reasons why the good old parallel port can still be found on modern computers.  I myself have witnessed the following with my own two eyes:

- [Software protection dongles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_protection_dongle).  There are still many old and esoteric scientific/engineering applications in use that use the parallel port for their anti-piracy dongles.  One I saw recently was for calculating mineral densities from the sample data taken from a gas spectrometer.  No need to update an app like that because all it does is a single, very specific kind of math problem.  It does, however, benefit from running on a faster computer than the ones available when it was written, and the dongle lets you replace the computer with ease.
- Heavy industrial equipment interfaces.  Think computerized textile looms, assembly line robots, parcel sorting machines, etc.  These devices have a service life of decades -- much longer than the computer that controls them could be expected to last.  Many of them have been in use since the 1980's when parallel ports were not only common; they were the fastest connection available at the time.  I recently saw one being used by a plasma cutter making custom ducting for an HVAC supplier.
- My son is in the Boy Scouts.  At their annual Pinewood Derby races, his troop has a track that records the race times over a parallel port and flags the winner from each round.
- Old large format/high-capacity printers.  Some of these things are 20 years old and still going strong.  They even still make parts for them.
- Some business are still using old Nortel PBX systems for their phones.  In the one I saw a couple years ago, a parallel port connected the PBX to the voice mail server.  It also used a WYSE dumb terminal to program it, which I was unable to figure out.

These are just the ones I've seen.  Remember that computers aren't just for playing games and goofing around on the Internet.  Some of them are built to get work done, and parallel ports often come in handy for that.

Comment: FWIW, of the 3 motherboard I have at home, only one has a parallel port, and it's from 2010.  The other 2 are about 2-4 years and have serial ports, but no parallel ports.  So I'd say in 2019 it's becoming increasingly rare to find motherboards with a parallel port.  IIUC one of the problems with the USB to Parallel ports is that parallel ports have an interrupt pin that interrupts the CPU, and USB can't emulate this.  If you really need a real parallel port, you can buy an add-on card for $25.

Comment: It should be noted many motherboards come with internal connectors for installing parallel and serial ports on expansion slots.

Answer (score 0):

Really the only answer to this question is the manufacturer decided to put the parallel port on the motherboard.  Some people may still find a use for such a port. What if you still have a device that you want to use or that you *need* to use that connects via this method?  You would have to have this connector then (yes there are adapters, but that would be no fun).

As [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port) states, it's considered a legacy port.  They do point out that some printer servers still use this connection, though ethernet has replaced lots of these.  So there's one way that they are still used in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The parallel port is not really common anymore, but a lot of people have an old (but perfectly functional) printer that still uses it.
There are also some other devices that use it like specialist development stuff (GPIB converters, EPROM programmers) and some IO interfaces for hobbyists (e.g. interfaces used to control a model-train setup from the computer to name just one example).

There are of course USB to Parallel converter cables around, but in most cases these don't work with older software that expects a real parallel port.

Putting a legacy parallel port on the motherboard isn't very expensive for the manufacturer and it just may make the motherboard that little bit more attractive to someone who has a genuine need for a parallel port.